# FTPClient Connection

Tags: java, ftp-client, ftp-server

I am using FTPClient class, It works fine when I create connection of FTPClient and use it in same method,

But the problem comes when I create connection of FTPClient in one method and pass this object to another method then it throws exception says could not connect to FTP server.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

See if these examples you can solve your problem:

- [Java FTP Apache Commons Net 3.5](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)
- [Java FTP Commons Net 1.4.1 API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-1.4.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)